# Defining subspace of complex polynomials

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose I said:
$$
U = \{f(x) \in P_3(C): f(1) = 1\}
$$
What is $U$ exactly then?

My attempt is:

$P_3(C)$ is $\{1,x,x^2,x^3\}$

Of that, the ones that fit $f(1) = 1$ are $\operatorname{span}\{x, x^2, x^3\}$. Is that correct and the proper way to write it?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see you are trying to find a basis for the vector space
$$U=\{f\in P_3({\Bbb C})\,:\,f(1)=1\}\ .$$
But there is no way this will work since $U$ is in fact **not** a vector space: it does not contain the zero polynomial.

**Addendum**: answer to question raised in comments.  If
$$V=\{f\in P_3({\Bbb C})\,:\,f(0)=0\}$$
then we can write
$$\eqalign{V
  &=\{a+bx+cx^2+dx^3\,:\,a=0\ \hbox{and}\ b,c,d\in{\Bbb C}\}\cr
  &=\{bx+cx^2+dx^3\,:\,b,c,d\in{\Bbb C}\}\cr
  &={\rm span}\{x,x^2,x^3\}\ .\cr}$$

Comment: What if I said f(0) = 0, would that work?

Comment: See updated answer.